# Handling error from python listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling, listbox

```
def add_to_cart():
# Import globals as required
global item_images
global item_names
global item_prices
global count
global total_price

# Find required item details by using the active location of the listbox cursor
img_index = item_box.index(ACTIVE)
name_index = item_box.index(ACTIVE)
price_index = item_box.index(ACTIVE)
# Check listbox to make sure it has been populated and item is selected
#### Do i need this section ####
selection = item_box.curselection()
if selection:
    item_box.delete('0', END)
    item_box.insert(END, "Oops please select a category")
else:    
# Append cart lists ready for html invoice
    cart_imgs.append(item_images[img_index])
    cart_names.append(item_names[name_index])
    cart_prices.append(item_prices[price_index])
# Do i need this handle and if so how do i use it...
try:
    item_box.index = int(item_box.curselection()[0])
except IndexError:
    item_box.delete('0', END)
    item_box.insert(END, "Oops please select a category")
total_price = total_price + float(item_prices[price_index])

# Increase item count per button press.
count = count + 1
```

I have a list box that is acting as a shopping list. Users press a category button (computer/kitchen) that populates the list box and then they can select/add items to a cart which is later sent to HTML. I get an error that says  `cart_img.append(item_images[img_index])` list index is out of range.

I know this is because there is nothing in the list box when pressing add_to_cart func. (this is also because no category was selected first) I have included the if/else statement to attempt to hand this as well as the try/except error handle. I have found several posts that talk about a callback function and don't fully understand how to implement that in this situation.

Any help would be appreciated

My Original code was as follows and works fine if there is a category selected.

```
def add_to_cart():
# Import globals as required
global item_images
global item_names
global item_prices
global count
global total_price

# Find required item details by using the active location of the listbox cursor
img_index = item_box.index(ACTIVE)
name_index = item_box.index(ACTIVE)
price_index = item_box.index(ACTIVE)
# Append cart lists ready for html invoice
cart_imgs.append(item_images[img_index])
cart_names.append(item_names[name_index])
cart_prices.append(item_prices[price_index])
# Update total price for invoice
total_price = total_price + float(item_prices[price_index])
# Increase count per button press.
count = count + 1
```

Comment: could you give your full code? have you binded the Call back function `"add_to_cart"` to the listbox? Looks like you are accessing the list data which is not present, thus the index out of range error occurs

Comment: mm i can't give the full code, its an assignment and i have no doubt someone will copy it if its found. I am new to coding but can research it. Does binding the function to add_to_cart mean that if it fails it will proceed to run the call back? That would be my understanding of your response but again have only just started learning.

Answer (score -1):

```
def add_to_cart():
# Import globals as required
global item_images
global item_names
global item_prices
global count
global total_price
try:   
# Find required item details by using the active location of the listbox cursor
    img_index = item_box.index(ACTIVE)
    name_index = item_box.index(ACTIVE)
    price_index = item_box.index(ACTIVE)
# Append cart lists ready for html invoice
    cart_imgs.append(item_images[img_index])
    cart_names.append(item_names[name_index])
    cart_prices.append(item_prices[price_index])
# Update total price for invoice
    total_price = total_price + float(item_prices[price_index])
# Increase count per button press.
    count = count + 1
except:
    item_box.delete('0', END)
    item_box.insert(END, "PLEASE SELECT A CATEGORY BEFORE PROCEEDING")
```

Comment: fixed the issue i was having

Comment: Please explain what you did differently. Code-only answers are discouraged on this site, as it requires the reader to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character.